# Web infrastructure to check e-mail

Tags: javascript, email, web

I was thinking in a web service that would check a Gmail account, retrieve the e-mail attachments and generate an HTML page showing their size.

Which tools should I consider to build the infrastructure to check e-mail? May I do this in javascript?

Comment: Which resources are you planning to do that on? Running your own server on which OS?

Comment: I'm thinking in put it on gthub pages, but more suitable options might exist. Suggestions are welcome.